# 5-position switch in an HH Strat set up for a killswitch

Tags: electric-guitar, electronics

I am about to purchase a Strat-style guitar.  It has two humbuckers, and a 5-way switch.  It only has one tone and one volume.  I'd like to modify the 5-way switch so that one of the positions kills the neck humbucker.

Is this even possible?  What's the best way to do this?

Ideally, I'd like the second bottom-most position to be the killswitch.  (the one next to Bridge only)

Comment: 'kills the humbucker'? You mean make it run single-coil? The pickup would need to be wired to allow that. We'd need the original schematic to be certain.

Comment: The simplest way to achieve this would be to have a separate switch to interrupt any signal from any pup. It makes more sense, as you may want to use it from a different pup combination. Doing what you suggest will lose one pup combination - for what benefit?

Comment: I think we need clarification on the term 'kill' because with only 2 pups, a standard 5-pos switch would already be wired "weird"

Comment: I'm not sure how killswitch can be interpreted other than how @Tim described it.  I do understand that ideally a separate control would do this.  I really don't want to drill a hole in the body for a button or switch to do this.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've seen people do 5-way switches on HH configurations where the intermediate positions are coil taps or splits.

Comment: There's plenty of room in the scratchplate without cutting into the body.

Comment: It would be helpful if someone could attach a diagram of a 5 position switch. Perhaps there are several types? Also, from my experience some switches (or some position of switches) are more or less suitable to be a kill switch, depending on the cut off point. If you want to try to repeat what e.g. Buckethead is doing you need a kill switch that will respond well.

Comment: @Tim this is a Charvel.  I don't believe it's got the same façade that a true Strat has.

Comment: Extra information usually helps - as here!

Comment: “I'm not sure how killswitch can be interpreted other than...” – well, you described it as killing specifically one of the PUs, when what you actually mean is kill the whole guitar output.

Comment: @leftaroundabout You're right.  I was inarticulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard 5-way switch is a simple evolution of the old Strat 3-way switches, which consists of two linked 3-way selectors. The in-between positions just select two of the positions simultaneously, i.e. they put the inputs in parallel. In the standard Fender configuration, one of the linked switches is used only to select the separate tone pots, which may not be all that relevant to you, so you could use that sub-selector as the kill switch by repurposing one of the in-between positions as a short to ground. Just ignoring any tone pots for now (you can wire them independent of the PU selection somehow), and assuming you don't want any coil splitting, you can set up a kill switch for example like this:

[image: Schematic for the proposed kill-switch]

Of course, whether you want the kill position on the NeckH + MidS slot or the MidS + BridgeH one is trivial to change.

That said – I wouldn't do it this way. As Tim already commented, it's no problem installing a small dedicated kill switch in the scratch plate, no woodwork needed. Or you could replace one of the tone pots with such a switch. (A pull pot will likely be too slow for the kind of stuff you want to do with a kill switch.)

Comment: Cool.  This gives me hope.  Thanks for the theory.

Comment: Like the animation! Clever.

Answer (score 1):

There's the option of changing a volume pot. for a piggyback type (push/pull). With nothing connected to one position (up or down) it will work as a kill switch - and save any woodwork.

Comment: “Nothing connected” is not a good way to do this, because it makes the line very sensitive to interference. Shorting to ground is much quieter.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - fair enough - but that's easily solved using a tandem pot.